# Selenium Java CSS Selector bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

That code works very fine! Finds my only one button in that span tag, and clicks.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[id$=somePagesCollection] a")).click();
```

Then, after clicking button, appears input field.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[id$=somePagesCollection] input[id$=somePagesCollection_0_url]")).sendKeys("some");
```

What i've got?

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[id$=somePagesCollection]
>   input[id$=somePagesCollection_0_url]"} Command duration or timeout: 16
>   milliseconds

Looking into the outer html of that element. What i'm doing wrong?

```
<input id="s567bb2e58337a_somePagesCollection_0_url" name="s567bb2e58337a[somePagesCollection][0][url]" required="required" class=" form-control" type="url">
```

Example from browser console.

```
$('span[id$=somePagesCollection] input[id$=somePagesCollection_0_url]').hide()
```

Another example from browser console that works well, but not in selenium.

```
$('span[id$=somePagesCollection] tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) input').hide()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting for the element before sending data

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span[id$=somePagesCollection] input[id$=somePagesCollection_0_url]"))).sendKeys("some");
```